# Correct way to stub a class method with a mock object that has a expectation set on it in Rspec 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Here's a working test, which Rspec tells me is now wrong because `stub!` is deprecated:

```
it 'paginates the right number of times' do
  mock_thing = mock_model(User)
  User.stub!(:page).and_return(mock_thing)
  mock_thing.should_receive(:per).with(50)
  get :index
end
```

What's the right way to do this? I tried the code below, but it fails:

```
it 'paginates the right number of times' do
  mock_thing = mock_model(User)
  mock_thing.should_receive(:per).with(50)
  User.stub(:page, mock_thing) do
    get :index
  end
end

# Error:
# RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: Double "User_1001" received unexpected 
# message :[]= with (:expected_from, ...Stacktrace removed
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem statement is:

```
User.stub!(:page).and_return(mock_thing)
```

which requires the monkey patching of `Object` to support the `stub` method.

You can explicitly enable the `should` syntax to get around the deprecation warning, but the way to express this with the new syntax is:

```
allow(User).to receive(:page).and_return(mock_thing)
```

I haven't reviewed the rest of your example for reasonableness.